# EF Core - cannot get discriminator value after upgrade to .net 6 in only one table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, migration, ef-core-6.0

Upgrading a .Net Core 3.1 MVC app to .NET 6. Followed the Migration document to upgrade the target framework, updated all the dependencies, replaced IdentityServerAuthentication with JwtBearer, disabled the new nullable stuff with `<nullable>Disable</nullable>` and was able to compile and run the project.

Most database access seems to work fine, but getting a strange error when trying to get data from one table. I thought it might be a problem with the Linq query, but also get the error when I run `dbContext.DbSetName.ToList()`. Both async and sync versions through the error.

The error thrown is: ([entire stacktrace in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bn5iCxNG))

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(Object value, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityShaperExpression.GenerateMaterializationCondition(IEntityType entityType, Boolean nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalEntityShaperExpression.GenerateMaterializationCondition(IEntityType entityType, Boolean nullable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityShaperExpression..ctor(IEntityType entityType, Expression valueBufferExpression, Boolean nullable, LambdaExpression materializationCondition)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateShapedQueryExpression(IEntityType entityType, SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I've traced this to the [EntityShaperExpression class in EF Core, line 139](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Query/EntityShaperExpression.cs), the `concreteEntityTypes[i].GetDiscriminatorValue()` is returning null, which then throws the `Argument types do not match` in the `Expression.Constant` method.

Now I'm trying to figure out why one Entity of about 170 is having issues with a discriminator.

I edited the Entity config to specifically have a discriminator but that resulted in an empty migration as EF already picked up the `[Key]` as being the discriminator.

These are somewhat edited for brevity but my current config looks like:

```
builder.Entity<OpOrganisation>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    entity.ToTable("tblOrganisation", "org");

    entity.HasDiscriminator(x => x.Id);

    // other properties
}


public class OpOrganisation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

modelBuilder.Entity("DOE.Code.NetCore.Data.Models.Entities.OpOrganisation", b =>
{
    b.Property<int>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .HasColumnName("intOrganisationId");

    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);
    
    b.ToTable("tblOrganisation", "org");

    b.HasDiscriminator<int>("Id");

    // other properties
});
```

Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this a TPH table? Why would you need a `.HasDiscriminator()` otherwise?

Comment: No, its per entity, but this entity originally inherited from another one and overrode some properties with `new` . I think the base library the overridden class came from was misconfigured as we got errors about the discriminator without the `HasDiscriminator`. I removed all that inheritance which didn't remove the error in question. I'm going to revert back to the inheritance today and see what happens and update my answer with any further findings. It seems EF Core 3.1 and EF Core 6 handle `HasDiscriminator` differently.

Comment: Using `Id` as `[Key]` and `Discriminator` looks very strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently someone had added a Discriminator in another part of the Entity Configuration class.

```
        builder.Entity<OpOrganisation>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasDiscriminator(x => x.Id);
        });
```

Removing this fixed the issue. Odd that we had to add this for it to work in EF Core 3.1 but then remove it for EF Core 6.